# HTTP status code for limited collection?

Tags: api, http, rest, http-status-codes

I have a restful service where one of the collections is limited (for UX reasons). In this case it has a cap of 25 items. If that is exceeded resources must be deleted before more can be added. As an example if a client submits:

```
POST http://somesite.com/api/v2/stuff
{"cool":"stuff"}
```

and there are < 25 things in stuff:

```
200 OK
```

if > 25 things in stuff:

```
???

DELETE http://somesite.com/api/v2/stuff/:id

POST http://somesite.com/api/v2/stuff
{"cool":"stuff"}

200 OK
```

What is the best code for this? Straight 400? 409 CONFLICT? 429? None seem quite right..

Comment: 409 Conflict seems right to me, because (a) it's a resource state problem and (b) it's user resolvable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use 409. From [httpbis section 7.5.8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-7.5.8):

> "The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
> state of the resource.  This code is only allowed in situations where
> it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
> resubmit the request.  The payload SHOULD include enough information
> for the user to recognize the source of the conflict."

In your case, the resource is the one identified by `http://somesite.com/api/v2/stuff`, and the `POST` request cannot be completed due to a conflict with its current state (which is that it is already maxed out). In your response, give the user enough info (preferably links) to delete one of the existing members, up the limit, or take some other action. Then they can resubmit the original request.

Comment: Yeah the description fits and I thought it might be best. Conflict just sounded a bit too .. crude =|